# iif blank show zero

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, iif

I have a visual studio report that I want to state that if a calculation box is blank due to there being no figures available on that particluar project then show zero.

My calculation is :-  `=((Sum(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "Accrued") + Sum(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "serv1")) / 
   (Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "serv1") + Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Accrued"))

  )`

And I want to try and include an IIF statement in that to show zero if blank.

Any ideas on how to best achieve my aim?

so far I have got to 
`=iif((Sum(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "Accrued") + Sum(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "serv1")) / 
   (Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "serv1") + Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Accrued"))

  ) = "" ,false,0 )`  but I am getting a little confused.

Comment: You want to apply IIF to the entire result?

Comment: You should show your attempt to use the IIf.

Comment: yes i would like my IIF to apply to the entire statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely value is not blank string but a `Nothing`. Try following construct:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(((Sum(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "Accrued") + Sum(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "serv1")) / (Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "serv1") + Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Accrued"))), 0, ((Sum(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "Accrued") + Sum(Fields!TotalCost.Value, "serv1")) / (Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "serv1") + Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "Accrued")))
```

It's a bit awkward since you have to repeat the expression twice, to avoid it you may want to write a custom function.